# SQL autoselecting date range based on today's day of the week

Tags: sql, parameters, date-range, sql-date-functions

--This is using SQL

I Have tried and failed at this a few times,

I have a sales table with an order date in the following format '2014-05-15 00:00:00.000'

I would like to have a report that runs on the basis that if @today is less than Friday, show last weeks date range, if @today is Saturday or Sunday, then use this weeks date range

assuming I only want to see the fields SalesOrder and OrderDate

Thanks in advance,

Dean

Comment: `if @today is less than Friday…` – did you mean to say, `if @today is *Friday or* less than Friday…`? Also, what have you got so far? In particular, how are you selecting the range regardless of the day of the week?

Comment: if 'today' is Friday (for example 5 as a week day number) so if 'today' < 5 then OrderDate between 'StartOFPrevWeek' and 'EndOfPrevWeek' 
if 'today' > 5 then 'OrderDate' between 'StartOfThisWeek' and 'EndOfThisWeek'. I have been struggling with the syntax for the clause, and how to define the parameters.

Comment: i have declared the parameters as date's with today as int

Comment: What to do in the case when `@today = 5`? And what should be start and end of the week? Monday till Friday? Monday till Sunday? Or perhaps Sunday till Saturday? Additionally, are you using SQL Server? If so, what does `SELECT @@DATEFIRST` return by default in your environment?

Comment: What are you writing this report in? You may wish to look at the 'day of the week' selector in the DATEPART function. Then build an IF ..... BEGIN....END ELSE IF ..... BEGIN...... END

Comment: im using SQL to write the query, then will be using report builder 3.0 for publishing it for users. sorry for being a pain ive been mulling over this for weeks and don't think I have the ability to write it for myself, could you give me an example query? thanks

Comment: select @@DateFirst returns 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweak to your hearts content (running this in SQL Server Management Studio will display messages with the correct outputs). Use the variables to filter your `SELECT` statement and remove the `PRINT` operators:

```
DECLARE @ReportDate DATETIME
DECLARE @StartOfWeek DATETIME
DECLARE @DayOfWeek INT 

SET @ReportDate = '2014-05-15 00:00:00.000' --This will be your variable in report builder
SET @DayOfWeek = DATEPART(dw,@ReportDate)

/* 
Take away the day of the week from the report date to
get the beginning of that week.
*/

--Adjust the +1 to mark the start of your week (ie. +2 makes Monday the start)
SET @StartOfWeek = DATEADD(dd, (-(@DayOfWeek) + 1), @Reportdate)

--Now do stuff based on the report date (set the beginning of the week)
IF @DayOfWeek BETWEEN 2 AND 5 --Friday is day 6 (Sunday is first day in SQL and the BETWEEN clause is inclusive)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Monday to Thursday' --This line can be removed
    /* Now minus 7 to get the beginning of the previous week */
    SET @StartOfWeek = DATEADD(dd, -7, @StartOfWeek)
END
---------------------------------------------------
/*
This entire box is optional (can be removed) but just for demonstration purposes to
show that the date stuff works
*/

IF @DayOfWeek = 6 --Friday is day 6 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Friday'
END
IF @DayOfWeek IN (7,1) --Saturday day 7, Sunday day 1
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Saturday or Sunday'
END
---------------------------------------------------

--This is where your SELECT statement goes (instead of PRINT operators below)
PRINT 'StartOfWeek = ' + CAST(@StartOfWeek AS NVARCHAR(255))
PRINT 'EndOfWeek = ' + CAST(DATEADD(dd,7,@StartOfWeek) AS NVARCHAR(255))
```

Comment: Thanks Kindly! ill test it out and hopefully not pester you any more!

Comment: @JustAnAverageSQLuser Did this solution work for you?